# Debugging Windows Forms application that accepts command line arguments in Visual Studio

Tags: .net

I created the application in Windows Forms that checks, if it contains specific command line arguments and acts accordingly.

Now I would like to test/debug my code with different command lines arguments.

I entered command line arguments by clicking on my project and choosing Properties/Debug.
But when I start the debugging, I receive following message

> The current project settings specify that the project will be debugged    with specific security permissions. In this mode, command line arguments will not be passed to the executable.

In Properties/Security, *"This is full trust application"* is selected, so I am not sure why it is complaining.

Comment: Passing command line arguments is not an option in a ClickOnce deployed app.

Answer (score 63, accepted):

You have setup ClickOnce publishing for this project, which adds a security restriction preventing command line parameters from being processed.

To remove the security restriction:

- Open Project Properties
- Go to the *Security* tab
- Unchecked the "Enable ClickOnce Security Settings"

Answer (score 15):

Go to the project properties *Security* tab and do this:

1. Click 'This is a partial trust application'
2. Click Advanced Button (toward the bottom)
3. Unclick 'Debug this application with the selected permission set'
4. Click <kbd>OK</kbd>
5. Click 'This is a full trust application' (this will undo step #1)

(Forum post *["command line arguments will not be passed" message](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/vstudio/en-US/ff3cda97-8772-4a62-a54b-e4faf5b8cffa/command-line-arguments-will-not-be-passed-message?forum=vsdebug)*.)