# Can't access command line after publishing application

Tags: vb.net, visual-studio, visual-studio-2013

I'm developing a Visual Basic application using Visual Studio. My application worked fine with command line arguments until I compiled a "Publish" the first time. Now if I try to run the executable file generated in the debug folder I get a `System.IndexOutOfRangeException` thrown. If I try to run it inside Visual Studio I get this warning:

> The current project settings specify that the project will be debugged with specific security permissions. In this mode, command line arguments will not be passed to the executable. Do you want to continue debugging anyway?

And then the code run without errors, *but* it does not create a new .exe file in the debug folder.

What have happened? How can I fix this problem? My code worked just fine until I tried to "publish" it. I haven't changed a single line.

Comment: Why are you trying to publish? Publish is for "run once" type applications. Locally installed (whether xcopy or msi) do not use publication.

Comment: Now I now it .... i'm a Newbie and I was just curious of  what would have happened....

Comment: @Richard: "run once"? Do you mean [ClickOnce](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ClickOnce)?

Comment: Related: *[Debugging Windows Forms application that accepts command line arguments in Visual Studio](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6738381)* (although I believe none of the answers really provides a solution - just make the symptoms go away).

Comment: I have a similar problem. A project that was working just fine for ***years*** suddenly got the same problem (perhaps I (or [AutoIt](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/AutoIt)) inadvertently changed some project setting). I have ***another*** project where specifying command-line parameters in Visual Studio works just fine without showing this problem (they are both ClickOnce applications). So it must be ***something else than using command-line parameters in Visual Studio*** - removing them makes the symptom go away, but the real problem must be something else.

Comment: @PeterMortensen That would seem likely, but it is 18 months ago….

Answer (score 0):

The "Publish" feature in Visual Studio uses ClickOnce deployment technology. There's a pretty good overview of ClickOnce, and how it differs from MSI deployment, at https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/142dbbz4(v=vs.90).aspx.

The MSDN topic "How to: Retrieve Query String Information in a ClickOnce Application" at https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms172242(v=vs.90).aspx confirms that "It is not possible to pass command-line arguments to a ClickOnce application. If you want to supply arguments to the application, you must deploy it over the Web and supply query string parameters in the URL."

You can create still create File Associations for a ClickOnce application, but it requires specific configuration steps as well as modified code. The following blog posting walks you through this:
http://blogs.msdn.com/b/mwade/archive/2008/01/30/how-to-add-file-associations-to-a-clickonce-application.aspx

Overall, unless you have a specific need to use ClickOnce, I would suggest sticking with XCopy or MSI deployment.